# Database table structure query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

Just a quick query on the best databased structure to go with for a small application, [ the database will be SqlLite or MySql and the app written in PHP if that helps]

Basically my issue is that entries will have many options and these will be likely to be added to and removed so editing the db structure is probably not the best idea. I am just wondering what the best way to store this options to the data base. In similar situations in the past I have achieved this by storing the data serialised or in JSON format to a table row, but I am wondering if this is the best option, any advice would be great.

The application is map based where a user can add/remove markers, the markers have types [ eg shop, school, hospital etc. ] the user can also add and remove types. In addition to this the use can create map views  eg a map where only the school and hospitals are visible.

It is a bit hard to describe but here is a go describing the [ simplified ] table structure

***markers***

```
+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----------+
|markerID | lat | lng | typeID | name      |
+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----------+
|1        | 52  | -9  | 1      | A School  |
|2        | 52  | -9  | 2      | A Shop    |
|3        | 52  | -9  | 1      | B School  |
|4        | 52  | -9  | 3      | A Hospital|
+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----------+
```

***marker types***

```
+-------+-------------+--------------+
|typeID | name        | icon         |
+-------+-------------+--------------+
|1      | Schools     | school.png   |
|2      | Shops       | shop.png     |
|3      | Hospitals   | hospitals.png|
+-------+-------------+--------------+
```

***map view***

```
+------+---------------------+---+
|mapID | name                | ??|
+------+---------------------+---+
|1     | Schoool & Shops     | ??|
|2     | Hospitals & Schools | ??|
+------+---------------------+---+
```

So my question is basically, what is the best way to store the information that mapID #42 should display markers with typeID #2, #5, and #23 for example.

Comment: You should indicate if any of our answers solve your problem, or if it still isn't what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand, the Map view could have many markers ( which is logic). so i think a join table would be the best solution. A table for example called MapMarkers that has the following structure : 
MapMarkers

```
 | id | MapID | MarkersID | ?? | ( you can add other infos for example if you want to store personnalized maps for each client you can add userID)
```

Comment: Not too sure how this would work, basicly each map would have a number of markertypes which would be displayed. eg in my example above mapID #2 should display the marker of both typeID #1 and typeID #3

Comment: if you are looking to have maps with predifined markers, then you should link the Map table and the MarkerType via another table, like the solution that @fàbio gave you. but if you want a personalized user map (a map where a user can put markers as he likes. then the best way to do this is by the solution i gave you plus a userID field). you can always implement the two solutions and give the user a more flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a third table which represents a relation between two tables:

mapView ---- < mapView-markerType > ---- markerType

mapView-markerType would have the attributes: | id | mapID | typeID |

(you should get a shorter name than mapView-markerType, obviously)

**EDIT**
Considering the changes you made on the post, you would get:

**mapView_markerType**

```
   id*    | mapId    | typeId
  --------|----------|----------
    1     | 1        | 1
    2     | 1        | 2
    3     | 2        | 1
    4     | 2        | 3
```

***EDIT2***

So, to further explain what I meant on the comment below:

***map view***

```
+------+---------------------+----------+
|mapID | name                | typeComb |
+------+---------------------+----------+
|1     | Schoool & Shops     |  {1,2}   |
|2     | Hospitals & Schools |  {1,3}   |
+------+---------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for that Fábio, you mean a forth table ? Do you think this is overkill, as I don't need to query/search for which marker types and displayed for which map, I just meed to return the marker types to display for a given map id ?. yes shorter name of course, these were just descriptive.

Comment: The solution I gave you follows the Normal Form. You could "break" the normal form rules, by using non-atomic values (for the sake of avoiding a fourth table). In the third attribute of your mapView table, you could write the id's as a set: {1,2} for Schools and Shops, or {1,3} for Schools & Hospitals. You could then parse that string (exploding by commas, for example). It's ugly, but it's faster! :)